# SQL Server Error, "Invalid usage of the option FIRST in the FETCH statement."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, offset-fetch

From 2012 onward the SQL Server docs show they support [`OFFSET..FETCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) which I'm trying to use instead of a `LIMIT`.

The following works fine in PostgreSQL to sample a result set,

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (1),(2),(3) ) AS t(x)
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

However, with SQL Server, I get

```
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
Invalid usage of the option FIRST in the FETCH statement.
```

What's going on here? Does SQL Server support the standardized `OFFSET` .. `FETCH`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SQL Server has implemented the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` clauses as part of the `ORDER BY` clause, as pointed by the other answers and documented in their documentation.

The SQL standard on the other side, has both of these clauses as independent:

```
<query expression> ::=
[ <with clause> ] <query expression body>
[ <order by clause> ] [ <result offset clause> ] [ <fetch first clause> ]
```

If someone wants this feature implemented in full compliance with the standard, they can always make a request to the SQL Server team, through the Connect channel. In fact, MS has commented - in a different request about offset and fetch:

> Connect item: [SQL Denali: add total rows counter to `SELECT` statement](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/622246/sql-denali-add-total-rows-counter-to-select-statement) - by Alexey Rokhin
>
> Answer: Posted by Microsoft on 24/11/2010 at 11:34
>
> The requirement **that `OFFSET/FETCH` requires `ORDER BY` is a restriction in this release.** In the ANSI SQL standard (SQL:2011) where the new `OFFSET/FETCH` clauses are proposed, `ORDER BY` is optional. The restriction in SQL Server has to do with limitation in our parser technology that cannot handle the optional syntax without making `OFFSET` a reserved keyword. **We may remove it in the future.**
>
> Now with respect to ...

Until then, if one wants to use `OFFSET` and `FETCH` without a specific `ORDER BY`, a workaround is to add a "do nothing" order by clause. Example:

```
SELECT 
...
ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 11):

As stated at the very top of the [documentation on `OFFSET`..`FETCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql)

> The OFFSET-FETCH clause provides you with an option to fetch only a window or page of results from the result set. **OFFSET-FETCH can be used only with the ORDER BY clause.**
>
> ...
>
> **ORDER BY is mandatory to use OFFSET and FETCH clause.**

So,

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (1),(2),(3) ) AS t(x)
ORDER BY t.[x]  /* <-- ADD ME TO BE HAPPY */
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Not all that practical for a simple `LIMIT` if that's what you're going for you'll want to stick with [`TOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql).

Answer (score 10):

According to [the reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql), the `OFFSET` clause is part of `ORDER BY` in SQL Server. You'll also need to add the `ROWS` keyword after the `OFFSET` specification:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (1),(2),(3) ) AS t(x)
ORDER BY x
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```